# How to implement the DoPair method under google tv pairing protocol by C++

Tags: google-tv

There are two program languages to implement the Google tv pairing protocol library:

1. JAVA version  <-- my reference sample
2. C++ version  <-- my target

I am implementing the connecting task of my pairing program. I found some JAVA sample code to call the pairing library just like [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/search?q=PairingContext&origq=PairingContext&btnG=Search+Trunk) .

A definition under the method 'attemptToPair' in the above link code :

```
PoloWireInterface protocol = 
              WireFormat.PROTOCOL_BUFFERS.getWireInterface(context);
```

I do not know how to implement this definition by calling the C++ version library.

Because the class 'PoloWireInterface' is just an abstract class under C++ version library.

In addition, no any other class extends PoloWireInterface under this library.
(Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-pairing-protocol/source/browse/#hg%2Fcpp%2Fsrc%2Fpolo%2Fpairing))

I can't establish an instance of 'ClientPairingSession' without the PoloWireInterface instance.

---

My client part pairing task as following code, but it is not work :'(

```
using namespace polo::pairing;

using namespace polo::wire;

using namespace polo::encoding;

X509* peer_cert = // peer side certificate, load by openssl

X509* local_cert = // local side certificate,  generate by openssl

PairingContext* context;

context = new PairingContext(local_cert,peer_cert,false);

// CPoloWireInterface extends abstract class PoloWireInterface
PoloWireInterface* protocol = new CPoloWireInterface(); 

PoloWireAdapter* wire = new protobuf::ProtobufWireAdapter(protocol);

PoloChallengeResponse* challenge;

challenge = new PoloChallengeResponse(local_cert,peer_cert);

ClientPairingSession* mClientPairingSession;

mClientPairingSession = new ClientPairingSession
    (wire, context, challenge, service_name, "AnyMote");

EncodingOption hexEnc(EncodingOption::kHexadecimal, 4);

mClientPairingSession->AddInputEncoding(hexEnc);

mClientPairingSession->AddOutputEncoding(hexEnc);

// CPairingListener extends abstract class PairingListener
PairingListener* listener = new CPairingListener(); 

mClientPairingSession->DoPair(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a exact match between the java and c++ library.
You should try this tutorial for working with c++ library:

https://google-tv-chrome-extensions.googlecode.com/git/LearningExerciseInstructions/instructions.html

Comment: Do you mean I can't call the library of google pairing directly, because it is not ready yet?

I found that APIs of 'google-tv-chrome-extension' are different with 'google-tv-pairing-protocol'.

May I have the source code of Anymote library under 'google-tv-chrome-extension' project? I want to override some functions of pairing task.